# Firestore admin transaction localized description

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am using transactions right now on a node.js server. Is there a way to print out the throw reason in the transaction error. Like does the error have a parameter of 'localized description' like it does on ios. I want to send the throw reason to the user in a readable form and not some error gibberish.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

```
var db = admin.firestore()
const docRef = db.collection('1234').doc('1234')

try {
    const res = await db.runTransaction(async t => {
        const doc = await t.get(docRef);
        const docData = doc.data()

        throw 'This is the throw message' // Example throw
    });
        console.log('Transaction success', res);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Transaction failure:', e);
    }
```

Example error that is not a cause of a throw.

```
Transaction failure: ReferenceError: nil is not defined
at file:///Users/MyUser/Desktop/MyServer/server.js:62:34
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
at async Transaction.runTransaction (/Users/MyUser/Desktop/MyServer/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/transaction.js:324:26)
at async thisFunction (file:///Users/MyUser/Desktop/MyServer/server.js:57:21)
```

Error message caused by a throw message

```
Transaction failure: This is the throw message
```

I would like to get just the failure message.

```
This is the throw message
```

Or the first one

```
nil is not defined
```

Comment: Hi, could you provide an example of your code?

Comment: @llompalles I provided an example

Comment: Hi! thanks you for the code. Since the error is being logged in that way by design I recommend you to open this issue in the repository for the [Nodejs Firebase SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues) so the development team would analyze the feasibility of implement a better logging.